# Rails MySql2 Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

getting error while connecting mysql with rails
here is error logs can any one help ?
there are many error logs but grep some which i think important
rails version - 5.2.3
ruby version - 2.5.1p57
mysql2 version 0.5.2
database.yml is

```
`default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  #encoding: utf8mb4
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  reconnect: false
  strict: false
development:
  <<: *default
  database: plum_nm
test:
  <<: *default
  database: plum_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= begin YAML.load(File.read(`echo $HOME`.squish + "/.app_config.yml"))["myapp_dbname"] || "" rescue "" end %>
  pool: 20
  username: <%= begin YAML.load(File.read(`echo $HOME`.squish + "/.app_config.yml"))["myapp_dbuser"] || "" rescue "" end %>
  password: <%= begin YAML.load(File.read(`echo $HOME`.squish + "/.app_config.yml"))["myapp_db"] || "" rescue "" end %>
  host: <%= begin YAML.load(File.read(`echo $HOME`.squish + "/.app_config.yml"))["myapp_host"] || "" rescue "" end %>
`
```

#mysql error while starting rails server

```
`rails s
Your Gemfile lists the gem sidekiq (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/builder-3.2.0/lib/builder/xchar.rb:111: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0081 p:---- s:0463 e:000462 CFUNC  :connect
c:0080 p:0612 s:0451 e:000450 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90 [FINISH]
c:0079 p:---- s:0437 e:000436 CFUNC  :new
c:0078 p:0104 s:0432 e:000431 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22
c:0077 p:0024 s:0425 e:000424 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811
c:0076 p:0021 s:0421 e:000420 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855
c:0075 p:0015 s:0417 e:000416 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834
c:0074 p:0014 s:0411 e:000410 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795
c:0073 p:0012 s:0405 e:000403 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523
c:0072 p:0038 s:0399 e:000395 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382
c:0071 p:0048 s:0392 e:000391 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1014
c:0070 p:0011 s:0386 e:000385 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118
c:0069 p:0004 s:0382 e:000381 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90
c:0068 p:0102 s:0378 e:000377 TOP    /home/lenovo/plum-dev/config/initializers/constants.rb:24 [FINISH]
c:0067 p:---- s:0375 e:000374 CFUNC  :load
c:0066 p:0011 s:0369 e:000368 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285
c:0065 p:0067 s:0366 e:000365 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257
c:0064 p:0015 s:0359 e:000358 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285
c:0063 p:0007 s:0352 e:000351 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:657
c:0062 p:0038 s:0349 e:000348 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170
c:0061 p:0017 s:0343 e:000342 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:656
c:0060 p:0007 s:0338 e:000337 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:614 [FINISH]
c:0059 p:---- s:0334 e:000333 CFUNC  :each
c:0058 p:0022 s:0330 e:000329 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613 [FINISH]
c:0057 p:---- s:0327 e:000326 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0056 p:0015 s:0322 e:000321 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32
c:0055 p:0019 s:0317 e:000316 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61
c:0054 p:0019 s:0313 e:000312 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228
c:0053 p:0005 s:0309 e:000308 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350
c:0052 p:0005 s:0305 e:000304 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422
c:0051 p:0109 s:0301 E:0012f0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431
c:0050 p:0059 s:0289 E:0006b8 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421 [FINISH]
c:0049 p:---- s:0283 e:000282 CFUNC  :each
c:0048 p:0011 s:0279 e:000278 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50 [FINISH]
c:0047 p:---- s:0273 e:000272 CFUNC  :call
c:0046 p:0075 s:0268 E:000f90 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415
c:0045 p:0031 s:0256 E:001e18 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349 [FINISH]
c:0044 p:---- s:0252 e:000251 CFUNC  :each
c:0043 p:---- s:0249 e:000248 CFUNC  :call
c:0042 p:0033 s:0245 E:000e60 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347
c:0041 p:0034 s:0237 E:000160 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226
c:0040 p:0033 s:0231 e:000230 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205
c:0039 p:0022 s:0224 E:0000f0 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60
c:0038 p:0023 s:0218 e:000217 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361
c:0037 p:0020 s:0213 e:000212 TOP    /home/lenovo/plum-dev/config/environment.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0036 p:---- s:0210 e:000209 CFUNC  :require_relative
c:0035 p:0006 s:0205 e:000204 EVAL   config.ru:3 [FINISH]
c:0034 p:---- s:0202 e:000201 CFUNC  :eval
c:0033 p:0033 s:0195 e:000194 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116
c:0032 p:0134 s:0187 e:000186 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:105
c:0031 p:0031 s:0178 e:000177 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:66
c:0030 p:0083 s:0171 e:000170 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:349
c:0029 p:0035 s:0165 e:000164 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:249
c:0028 p:0020 s:0161 e:000160 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27
c:0027 p:0019 s:0156 e:000154 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:422
c:0026 p:0004 s:0151 e:000150 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89
c:0025 p:0038 s:0146 E:000970 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51
c:0024 p:0042 s:0142 e:000141 BLOCK  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147 [FINISH]
c:0023 p:---- s:0138 e:000137 CFUNC  :tap
c:0022 p:0030 s:0134 e:000133 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142
c:0021 p:0064 s:0130 e:000129 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27
c:0020 p:0047 s:0122 e:000121 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127
c:0019 p:0259 s:0115 e:000114 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392
c:0018 p:0043 s:0102 e:000101 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65
c:0017 p:0134 s:0095 e:000094 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46
c:0016 p:0087 s:0084 e:000083 TOP    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0079 e:000078 CFUNC  :require
c:0014 p:0249 s:0074 e:000073 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32
c:0013 p:0053 s:0064 e:000063 TOP    /home/lenovo/plum-dev/bin/rails:9 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :load
c:0011 p:0134 s:0055 e:000054 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28
c:0010 p:0009 s:0050 e:000049 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7
c:0009 p:0014 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30
c:0008 p:0293 s:0039 e:000038 TOP    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0033 e:000032 CFUNC  :load
c:0006 p:0115 s:0028 e:000027 TOP    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :require
c:0004 p:0129 s:0017 e:000016 TOP    /home/lenovo/plum-dev/bin/spring:15 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0012 e:000011 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0018 s:0007 E:001388 EVAL   bin/rails:3 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:002020 (none) [FINISH]`
```

i have tryed with all older version of mysql also try with reinstalling
rails, mysql and mysql2 gem